# Apply Coupon code on the final total amount, not cart total

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Apply Coupon code on the final total amount, not cart total:

```
/*Installtion Chrages Discount */

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'mysite_box_discount', 10, 1);
function mysite_box_discount( $cart )
{
     $installation_price = 100;
     $cart->add_fee( __($cartQty.'Installation', 'woocommerce'),$installation_price,false );
      global $woocommerce;  

    if(WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons()){
     
         $coupon_code = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code[0]);

        $coupon_amount = (float) $coupon->amount;
        $discount_on_fee = (float) $coupon_amount/100;  
       
        $installation_discount  =  $discount_on_fee*$installation_price;

        $cart->add_fee( __($cartQty.'Installation Discount', 'woocommerce'), -$installation_fee_discount,false );

    }

 }
```

This apply discount but I need complete total discount including fees too.

Comment: You simply can't apply a coupon on the final total amount, as you are going to make an infinite loop.

Comment: so how to achive this?

Comment: Coupons only can get applied on cart content total (cart items total)t

Comment: @LoicTheAztec there is a variable product called installation charges. I have considered it as a fee and add on cart_total_calcualte hook. Now I need a discount on fees too. I am done with adding fees but I can't understand how to deal with the total discount?

Comment: Coupons doesn't handle fees or shipping. May be you can hook on fees and change the fee amount based on coupon discount, but I have never done that before.

Comment: can you advise me on how to deal with this? Actually, we are selling software if users need installation at home then we charge for that. For example,

MSOFFICE 1000RS and Installtion charge 100RS (Fees) So its 20% discount (-220)

Comment: Sorry I don't know, as I have told you, I have never tried to do something similar.